# Deploying new version (com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Starting from yesterday trying to upload a new version of my app (changed only client side code), is giving me the following exception (app id is "riparautonline-hrd"):

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:158)
    at com.riparauto.server.guice.RestGuiceConfig.<init>(RestGuiceConfig.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.newListenerInstance(WebXmlConfiguration.java:650)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:631)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:452)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:459)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:701)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:336)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:328)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:456)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Does someone has/had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing out any compiled classes, and recompiling.   I've seen that sort of thing when changing the AE sdk version.  I had to delete war/WEB-INF/classes I think.  I deleted that and everything compiled though so maybe it was something else.  I suspect it was an old class though.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that jsr305.jar is included in your classpath